# Java: Inheriting class can not be converted to super class in method parameter

Tags: java, inheritance, parameters, casting, parameter-passing

I have this method with a generic class as parameter:

```
myMethod(Class myclass){
    Superclass superclass = myclass;
}
```

then I use the method by passing a child class of the Superclass

```
myMethod(Mychildclass.class)
```

Netbeans is giving me a warning that I am using generic "Class". However this works fine.
If I change the method's parameter to this more specific

```
myMethod(Class<Superclass> myclass){
    this.superclass = myclass;
}
```

then I am getting an error when trying to use my method:

```
incompatibles types: Class<Mychildclass> cannot be converted to Class<Superclass>
```

So my question: Why is this not working? How can I make Netbeans happy giving me no warning and no error messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
private Class<? extends Superclass> superclass;

void myMethod(Class<? extends Superclass> myclass){
    this.superclass = myclass;
}
```

- If you use `Class<Superclass>`,
  only `Superclass.class` is expected.
- If you use `Class<? extends Superclass>`,
  `Superclass.class` or any of its child classes are expected.

Comment: Thanks! That works, however it does not work without a cast which is "unchecked":
     this.superclass = (Class<Supeclass>) myclass;
Netbeans tells me: "required:Class<Superclass> found:Class<CAP#1>"

Comment: @BenediktVogler the same goes for the `superclass` member. For avoinding the cast set its type to `Class<? extends Superclass>`. I have updated my answer for reflecting this point.